# Знание переходности глаголов чем-то может помочь в изучении языка? Влияет на что-нибудь?

Tags: глаголы, преподавание

Например, с каким падежом употребляется, какие причастия и деепричастия образуются.
Точнее: полезное ли это знание для изучения русского языка иностранцем, или об этом можно не упоминать?

Comment: Для иностранцев очень полезно (только без причастий и деепричастий, потому что их уже по стандартному алгоритму можно образовывать). Для русских школьников бесполезное знание, на мой взгляд. Оно и так понятно. Просто упомянуть и ехать дальше.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема в том, что я пока не придумал, в каких ситуациях это знание может помочь иностранному ученику. (А вопрос такой возник)
В отличие от: совершенный вид или нет, регулярное действие или нет, возвратный или нет, и т.п., где действительно важно знать, чтобы выбрать правильный глагол.

Comment: Ну это знание за рамками грамматики. Также как и употребление предлогов с существительными. (На Украину. В Россию итд.) Поэтому для учебника оно мало подходит. Но по сути это и есть язык.

Answer (score 1):

**Переходность** надо понимать всем — носителям зыка и изучающим язык иностранцам.  Не надо думать, что это простая формальность. Поэтому перейдем сразу **к практике вопроса** и рассмотрим переходный глагол ***видеть***.

1. В этой теме важно работать **[с толковым словарем](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x).** Глагол многозначный, но почти во всех значениях присутствует вопрос В.п (***кого-что***). Исключением является первое значение (иметь зрение: он хорошо видит).
   В остальных случаях  прямое (беспредложное) дополнение в В.п. является **обязательным.**  И мы делаем вывод: в большинстве случаев это **переходный глагол.**
2. Переходные глаголы используются  с **обязательным прямым дополнением,** что можно проверить в словаре по падежному вопросу. А иначе его семантика будет **невыраженной**, то есть это будет **ошибка**, неправильно построенная речь.
3. Такое управление в грамматике называется **сильным**, оно характерно для переходных глаголов.  Вопрос о сильном и слабом управлении обсуждался на форуме [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474701/Как-отличить-сильное-управление-от-слабого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474701/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)
4. **Предложный падеж?** Переходные глаголы  используются с этим падежом: *Я вижу (кого?) **птицу**  (на чем?) **на дереве**.* Он не запрещен, но это управление не является сильным (обязательным). Переходный глагол может обойтись без этого распространителя.

**А как с другими падежами?** Там сильное управление встречается, но редко. В любом случае это надо контролировать по словарю по падежному вопросу.

5. Переходность надо усчитывать при образовании **причастий**: так, страдательные причастия образуются **только от переходных глаголов** (обязательное присутствие объекта): увиденный, видимый.

**Приложение** (определения в теме)

**Переходность** — грамматическая глагольная категория, которая выражает отношения между субъектом и объектом действия. **Переходный глагол** — глагол, употребляемый с существительным в винительном падеже без предлога в значении прямого объекта действия Грамматически противопоставлен **непереходному** глаголу. **Переходные глаголы** — это глаголы, действие которых переходит на предмет или объект.

Answer (score 0):

Пока единственная обнаруженная мной связь это то, что с предложным падежом употребляются ТОЛЬКО непереходные глаголы. Однако, насколько это может помочь иностранцу - вопрос открытый :)

Comment: Насколько иностранцу может помочь изучение основных 100-а глаголов русского языка? На много. А что значит изучение глаголов? Это изучение контекста употребления, падежей, предлогов. Всякой мелочевки, которая с "грамматикой" не имеет ничего общего. Однако эти 100 условных глаголов это ,можно сказать, база языка.

Comment: Согласен, конечно :) Спасибо.
Просто в преподавании иностранцам возникает вопрос: нужно ли засорять головы учеников терминами и определениями, которые напрямую не влияют на усвоение языка, а просто описывают его. У них и так головы пухнут от русского :D

Answer (score 0):

Это знание может пригодиться в двух случаях:

1. Если вы иностранец и изучаете русский язык. Про это уже говорили в комментариях, и про это упоминал в своём ответе `@ViktorKovaliov`. Дело в  том, что русский язык сложен для изучения (раз даже для его носителей сделали отдельный сайт!), и изучающим русский язык людям нужно знать: может ли глагол сочетаться с винительным падежом без предлога.
2. В морфологическом разборе глагола необходимо указывать его переходность. То есть школьникам нужно знать, что такое переходный глагол =).