# Как отличить сильное управление от слабого?

Tags: управление

Не очень понятно, является ли тип управления постоянным качеством глагола?

Не очень понятно, как определяется тип управления глагола?

Например:
**сломать игрушку** (в учебнике написано, что это **сильное** управление). Почему, ведь мы можем сказать "сломать ногой"/сломать о стол и т.д.

Другой пример:
**оттолкнуться от берега** (тоже сильное), можем же сказать "оттолкнуться веслом"

Как четко определить тип управления?

Comment: Похожий вопрос, но без ответа  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473951/Сильное-и-слабое-управление-в-чем-разница

Comment: @Sharon Хотелось бы и ответ знать)

Comment: Да,  я даже собиралась ответить, но почему-то передумал. а материалы остались. Но хочется сначала послушать других. Вопрос очень правильный.

Comment: Да, мне бы тоже хотелось услышать внятное разъяснение. Я ведь даже пытался разобраться, что это такое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Теория**

**Определение** сильной и слабой связи можно прочитать в статье[«Виды подчинительной связи в словосочетании»](https://studopedia.su/16_49850_trudnie-sluchai-imennogo-i-glagolnogo-upravleniya.html)

**Разграничение** сильного и слабого управления впервые было сделано А.М.Пешковским («Русский синтаксис в научном освещении», 1956 г.).

При **сильном** глагольном управлении зависимый компонент является **обязательным**, без него глагол будет семантически недостаточным, и это основное определение. **Переходность** — только частный вид семантической недостаточности. Сильное управление может быть также обусловлено наличием **приставок**.

При **слабом** управлении зависимый компонент лишь возможен, но **не обязателен.**

**Формы зависимого компонента** для каждого глагола можно посмотреть в толковом словаре.

**2. Решение**

В приведенных примерах даны  глаголы с сильным управлением. В этом случае зависимый компонент обязателен.

**Пример 1.** ***Сломать игрушку*** (сильное управление). Это **переходный** глагол, обязательным компонентом является только прямое дополнение "игрушку", что указано в словаре.

**ЛОМАТЬ**, нсв. ***кого-что***. 1. (св. сломать). Сгибая, перегибая или ударяя с силой, разделять на части, куски.

***Сломать ногой/сломать о стол*** и т.д. — эти распространители в общем случае необязательны, их нет в словаре.

**Пример 2.** ***Оттолкнуться от берега*** (тоже сильное управление). Это определяется наличием **приставки ОТ**.

**ОТТОЛКНУТЬСЯ**, св. 1. ***от кого-чего***. Упёршись во что-л., толчком отодвинуться. О. от берега.

***Оттолкнуться (чем?) веслом*** — необязательный распространитель (хотя и частый), в словаре его нет.

**3. Примеры**

*Потом **сломали печати,** вскрыли футляр – и он извлёк оттуда пергаментный свиток.*

*Чтобы лодка поплыла, нужно как следует **оттолкнуться от берега**.*

*Вода в 800 раз плотнее воздуха, а кроме того, практически несжимаема, поэтому **от неё** и удаётся **оттолкнуться веслом.***

*Он изо всех сил **оттолкнулся рукой и ногой от скалы**, и в то же мгновение на то место, где он только что находился, обрушился угловатый камень...*

*Последовавшая затем попытка **оттолкнуться руками от дна** не принесла успеха.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147840/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.